# Unable to send mail from bot integrated with slack

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, smtp, botframework, slack

I have a bot made in framework v4 using c#.The bot send a email to admin if doesn't able to fetch answer from qna maker.It completely working fine on local emulator, i am able to the mail but when published over slack the bot throw a error.
Here is code
 private async Task ProcessSampleQnAAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

```
        var results = await _botServices.SampleQnA.GetAnswersAsync(stepContext.Context);
        if (results.Any())
        {
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(results.First().Answer), cancellationToken);

        }
        else
        {
            var question = stepContext.Context.Activity.Text;
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(_configuration["DefaultAnswer"]), cancellationToken);

            string mailbody = "<h4><b>Hi Admin , following question was not answered from bot :  </b> </h4>" + question;
            Common objCommon = new Common(_configuration);
            objCommon.SendEmail(_configuration["EmailSubject_UnAnswerQuestion"], mailbody);
        }


    }
```

**appsetting.json**

```
"AdminEmailAddress": "****@****.com", //to Email Address
"FromEmailAddress": "******@gmail.com", // From email address
"SMTP_Host": "smtp.gmail.com", // SMTP client Host Name
"SMTP_Port": "587", // SMTP port number
 "SMTP_UserName": "****@gmail.com", // email server user name (Email server 
 network credentials)
 "SMTP_Password": "******", // email server password (Email server network 
credentials)
 "EmailSubject_UnAnswerQuestion": "Question whose answer not found", // 
Subject string for un- answere question email.
"DefaultAnswer": "Sorry, could not find an answer in the Q and A system.", // 
default answere if answere not found in QnA.
 "DelayTimeInSeconds": "60" // Feed back dely time in seconds.
```

**Common logic of smtp**

> ```
> public class Common
> {
>     private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
>      public Common(IConfiguration configuration)
> {
>     _configuration = configuration;
> }
> public bool SendEmail(string subject, string mailbody)
> {
>    string to = _configuration["AdminEmailAddress"];   //To address    
>     string from = _configuration["FromEmailAddress"];  //From address    
>     MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
>     message.Subject = subject;
>     message.Body = mailbody;
>     message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
>     message.IsBodyHtml = true;
>     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(_configuration["SMTP_Host"], 
>   int.Parse(_configuration["SMTP_Port"])); //Gmail smtp    
>     System.Net.NetworkCredential basicCredential1 = new
>     System.Net.NetworkCredential(_configuration["SMTP_UserName"], 
>    _configuration["SMTP_Password"]);
>     client.EnableSsl = true;
>     client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
>     client.Credentials = basicCredential1;
>     try
>     {
>         client.Send(message);
>         return true;
>     }catch (Exception ex)
>     {
>         throw ex;
>     }}
> ```

Comment: Please include the error you receive.

Comment: @ mdrichardson - MSFT,,,, its show over slack that bot has a error , please fix it,

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. What error is shown in Slack? What errors show in the console logs of your bot? I don't have nearly enough information to begin making suggestions to fix things. Please do some debugging and tell me as much as you can about the error. It will be most helpful if you can [debug locally](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/)